# Error code 1 pip installing -e . to gym retro on windows

Tags: python, openai-gym

i am trying to install and setup gym retro as per this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFa6NhLgeL0&list=PLTWFMbPFsvz3CeozHfeuJIXWAJMkPtAdS&index=2

but when i pip install -e . i get the error

```
Command "c:\users\liamp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\LiamP\\gym-retro\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\LiamP\gym-retro\
```

i tried re updating the submodules before building but that didnt fix.
i am installing it through the git CMD in python 3.6 on windows

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install [MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit](http://www.msys2.org/) first, as stated in [the gym-retro "install from source" documentation](https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing.html#windows-prerequisites):

> After you have installed msys2 open an MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit prompt
>   (under Start > MSYS2 64bit) and run this command:
>
> `pacman -Sy make mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`
>
> Once that’s done, close the
>   prompt and open a Git CMD prompt (under Start > Git) and run these
>   commands. If you installed MSYS2 into an alternate directory please
>   use that instead of `C:\msys64` in the command.
>
> `path %PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin`
>   `set MSYSTEM=MINGW64`

After that, you may run `pip3 install -e .` under the gym-retro directory. Note that you don't need to `clone gym-retro` if you have already done so. However, you must execute the `path`, `set` and `pip3 install` commands in the same terminal (i.e. without closing and reopening).